# Simple meaning of phrase "Who to my knowledge has never told a joke"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am watching / reading a Visual novel and I am having a little difficulty understanding this phrase. Is this some kind of idiom?

Here is the full sentence:

> ..I'm watching someone I know very well. A tall man with deep-featured face, who to my knowledge has never told a joke, is patting my head.

Comment: A tall man (with deep-featured face), who (to my knowledge) has never told a joke, is patting my head. If you get rid of all modifiers, it becomes "A tall man is patting my head."

Comment: ohh i understand, so this is adding extra information about that person. Right?

Comment: @VijayGautam Yep, it's not about who he told the joke to.

Comment: You can Google [to my knowledge](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=to+my+knowledge+definition). It means "as far as I know". Please make sure you capitalize the personal pronoun "I".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A tall man (with deep-featured face), who (to my knowledge) has never told
>   a joke, is patting my head.

is basically the same as the following sentence if you get rid of the prepositional phrases and relative clause.

> A tall man is patting my head

[To my knowledge](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20my%20knowledge%20definition&rct=j) means "as far as I know".

Answer (score 2):

*the man  have had a rough life*

(the deep-featured face could be telling us this)

*and because of this he haven't had much sense of humour so the jokes are not part of his person*

Despite this he takes time to cheer up his friend by patting his head

Comment: The question was about the direct meaning of a phrase the OP didn't understand. Answering with your interpretation of what the writer wanted to imply is not helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm am not a native speaker of the English language and simply tried to help a fellow learner.

Comment: @Sonea thanks for your help,your answer indeed helped me but Rathony's comment is much simpler and helpful for me, btw I up-voted  :)